# Android studio Ver 2.2 Gradle Sync Errors

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to make my first app, gradle brings the errors below on sync. am very new to android programming. Please help

> Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1

Comment: post your gradle file content.

Comment: which one exactly?

Comment: build.gradle(Project:app) content// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have offline compilation enabled for Gradle?
Try disabling it Android Studio settings.

Comment: it is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

just copy this code in your gradle , in the android {} body ...

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
} }
```

then sync it ...